# Grails RestBuilder casts an error

Tags: rest, grails

I'm using the grails RestBuilder plugin, but when i'm trying to send a post request with xml the exception is thrown:

```
Cannot cast object '<BookingRetrievalRQ xmlns="http://www.expediaconnect.com/EQC/BR/2014/01"><Authentication username="testuser" password="ECLPASS"/></BookingRetrievalRQ>' 
with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'grails.converters.XML'
```

But I do not understand why it occurs.

Thats my code request inside a service class:

```
def resource = XmlUtil.marshal(msg)
    def rest = new RestBuilder()
    def resp = rest.post('https://simulator.expediaquickconnect.com/connect/br') {
        contentType "application/xml"
        xml resource
    }
    return XmlUtil.unMarshal(resp.xml, BookingRetrievalRS.class)
```

[XmlUtil.class]

```
static String marshal(def source) {
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter()
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(source.class)
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller()
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE)
        marshaller.marshal(source, writer)
        return writer.toString()
    }   


    static def unMarshal(String strXml, Class targetClass){
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(targetClass)
        def unMarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller()
        return unMarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(strXml))
    }
```

When I try this:

```
def rest = new RestBuilder()
def resp = rest.post("https://simulator.expediaquickconnect.com/connect/br") {
        accept 'application/xml'
        contentType 'application/xml'
                    xml {
                        BookingRetrievalRQ(xmlns: "http://www.expediaconnect.com/EQC/BR/2014/01") {
                            Authentication(username: "testuser", password: "ECLPASS")
                        }
                    }
            }
```

I have this error message:

```
unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Comment: Which library are you getting `XmlUtil` from?

Comment: Ok let me ask this way, What is the type of `resource`?

Comment: Can you also add the implementation of `XmlUtil`, the custom wrapper?

Comment: I edited the question inserting the code.

Comment: Are you sure you get an Object of type `BookingRetrievalRS` from `XmlUtil.unmarshal()`?

Comment: Yep! But i not understand the relation with the expcetion.

Comment: I suppose somewhere in controller you are casting the result from unmarshalling to an XML again using `gails.converters.XML` where it expects to be an object or a map but getting a string. Add full stacktrace to see what actually is going on?

Comment: But look the documentation: http://springsource.github.io/grails-data-mapping/rest-client/api/grails/plugins/rest/client/RequestCustomizer.html#xml%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Disclaimer: This was extracted from the question.</sub>

I solved the problem by registering a bean in dev mode using this tutorial: [java https problem](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-fix-certificate-problem-in-HTTPS.html)